# how to install jbpm without internet

Tags: jbpm

I want to install JBPM 7.7 on a computer which don't have any internet access. I used an Internet computer  I followed this installation https://www.jbpm.org/learn/gettingStartedUsingSingleZipDistribution.html.
The JBMP started and I can login to business-central but not every thing is working fine and it seems there is some dependencies needs to be downloaded.

Is there any solutions ? .

Thanks :)